# Function argument reports "error expected pattern, found keyword `mod`"

Tags: function, rust

I have a barebones function in a class, this is the only function.

```
pub fn getfreq(note: char, mod: char, oct: i8) {}
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: expected pattern, found keyword `mod`
 --> src/main.rs:1:28
  |
1 | pub fn getfreq(note: char, mod: char, oct: i8) {}
  |                            ^^^
```

Is `mod` something Rust related? I just want to use it for abbreviating 'modifier'.

Comment: `mod` stands for [modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#defining-modules).

Comment: Oh damni! I knew it. But is there no way for me to call the parameter mod then?

Comment: Opinion: you should just call it `modifier`. Variable and function names are part of your documentation; don't make up obscure abbreviations. Is `oct` short for `octal` or `octave`? When you come back to this code in 3 months, how long will you futilely search your source code for "frequency" before you remember that you abbreviated `get_frequency` to `getfreq`? Short names may save seconds (debatably), but descriptive names can save minutes or more in the long run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I just want to use it for abbreviating 'modifier'.

`mod` is already used by the Rust language to abbreviate ["module"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/crates-and-modules.html). As such, it is a *keyword* — a specific set of characters that **cannot** be used for anything else. You will need to pick another name.

There are [many keywords in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/grammar.html#keywords) and you must not use them except for their language-specific purpose.

Comment: Still, it really seems stupid to define a module inside a functions arguments...Oh well.

Comment: @VikingPingvin you cannot define a module inside the arguments; it's just an artifact of how the compiler operates. I'd encourage you to try writing a lexer/parser to understand why concepts like keywords make programming languages easier to handle for humans, compilers, editors, etc.